# Selecting and Echoing Tags in Order from relation

Tags: php

```
$query "SELECT t.id FROM tags t, posts_tags pt WHERE pt.tag_id = t.id AND pt.post_id = :post_id";
```

using this query to relate these 3 tables

$query "SELECT t.id FROM tags t, posts_tags pt WHERE pt.tag_id = t.id AND pt.post_id = :post_id";
using this query to relate these 3 tables

```
  [     POSTS     ]  [     TAGS   ]  [           POSTS_TAGS             ]
  | id |   title  |  | id |  name |  | id |  post_id | tag_id | tag_type|
  |----|----------|  |----|-------|  |----|----------|--------|---------|
  | 1  |   PHP7   |  | 1  | PHP   |  | 1  |     1    |    1   |    1    |
  | 2  |   HTML   |  | 2  | HTML  |  | 2  |     1    |    2   |    1    |
  | 3  |   CSS3   |  | 3  | CSS   |  | 3  |     1    |    3   |    2    |
  _________________  ______________  | 4  |     2    |    2   |    3    |
                                     | 5  |     2    |    3   |    2    |
                                     | 6  |     3    |    3   |    3    |
                                     ____________________________________
```

How do i call the tags sorted like this

```
Title: PHP7
Tags:
     Lv1: PHP, HTML
     Lv2: CSS
     Lv3: 

Title: HTML
Tags:
     Lv1:
     Lv2: CSS
     Lv3: HTML
```

Its somehow simplified as

```
Lv(n) = tag_ids WHERE tag_type = (n)
```

I want to echo it like this

```
  echo"  
    <a>$tag</a>  //LV1
    <a>$tag</a>  //LV2
    <a>$tag</a>  //LV3
     ";
```

instead of using 3 queries using `"WHERE tag_type = 1 ~ 2 ~ 3"`